# Is it possible to trigger sender object's event (handler) and how?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, object, dynamic

I have a user interface control with multiple user interface objects that have different event handlers subscribed to their double click events, is there a way to fire that double click event in response to, say, a keydown event something like this:

```
 private void UIObject_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
      {
           ((Control)sender).DoubleClick.Trigger(); //note: senders of varied types
      }
 }
```

?
VSI says '....DoubleClick can only appear on the left hand side of -= or +=', so adding a callable method to the two different possible sender object types seems my simplest hope, but something like :.Perform[[Double]]Click() would just be so much better than dunch.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.  Events can only be triggered from the type in which they are defined.  That is, unless you have your own type (in which case you could expose a method that triggers your event).

Depending on how you are attaching the event handlers, you may be able to create a separate object that has a delegate/event to which all of the same handlers can also be added; this will allow you fire/invoke that instead of the `Control` object's method.

Comment: Seems reasonable that .NET is designed to prevent stacking events,  can you give me a source link on this?

Comment: @stackuser83 Well, attempting to do so is a compiler error, which specifically states that it can only be done from within the type.  I'm sure it's in the language specs somewhere, but I'd think the compiler is sufficiently reliable enough to believe that it's true.

Answer (score 0):

You can call event handlers directly, so long as they're visible (i.e. `private` in the same class, or `public`/`internal` in another class).

```
 private void UIObject_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
      {
           OtherUIObject_DoubleClick(sender, e); 
           // You can replace "sender" with "this", and/or replace "e" with a new EventArgs.
      }
 }
 private void OtherUIObject_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    // Code
 }
```

Comment: This will work only if the same handler is being used for all the DoubleClick events. That is not the case for the OP.

Comment: @mikez, the OP said "have different event handlers subscribed to their double click events" so it means this answer is might applicable :)

Comment: @spajce - No, I'm pretty sure mikez is right in this case.  I'll leave the answer in case it helps, but it's probably not going to.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to maintain a mapping of controls to delegates and then use the same double click and key down handlers for all of the controls.

```
private Dictionary<Control, Action> _controlsToActions = new Dictionary<Control, Action>() {
    { control1, method1 } // one for each control/handler pair
};

private void UIObject_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
      _controlsToActions[(Control)sender]();
    }
}

private void UIObject_DoubleClick(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    _controlsToActions[(Control)sender]();
}
```

Comment: I will prob end up switch casing for all the possible instance objects that subscribe to the UIObject_KeyDown handler method, I think that is not dissimilar to your suggestion, but I don't know enough about C# Actions to say for sure if your suggestion is what I am looking for.